# How to use DownloadManager?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

There is something I don't understand about Android DownloadManager because if I download a file from Chrome (it's the same when I download a file from my own application) and while the file is being downloaded, if I take a look in `sdcard/Download` with a file explorer, I can see the file named with it's final name and with it's final size whereas the file is not available again.

So, I wonder how to know when the file is ok or not.

Oh sure, if I'm still running my application, I can just wait to be notified by he Broadcast receiver but that's a situation which could not occur for long time downloads.

If I leave my app and run it a moment after, how to check my downloads?

Comment: You mean you want to find status of download at time ?

Answer (score 1):

With **Curser** you can find status of your *file*. Your code maybe something like this :

```
mIdColumnId = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DownloadManager.COLUMN_ID);
    mTitleColumnId = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE);
    mStatusColumnId = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
    mReasonColumnId = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON);
    mTotalBytesColumnId = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES);
    mCurrentBytesColumnId = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR);
    mMediaTypeColumnId = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(DownloadManager.COLUMN_MEDIA_TYPE);
    mDateColumnId = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP);
```

By dividing **TOTAL_SIZE** and **DOWNLOAD_SO_FAR** you can find what percent of file downloaded.
for complete code take a look [this](https://github.com/yxl/DownloadProvider) library.

Comment: I assume it's useable as long as I don't quit my application, and in this situation, I can quietly wait for the notification that DownloadManager is supposed to send me when download is complete. But my problem is mainly when I leave my application and come back a moment later. I think I'm no more supposed to get informations from the DownloadManager right?

Comment: You need to call curser each time want to see list of download files and status of them

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks a lot.